# Read certain values in a string PERL

Tags: perl, ip, uri, port

I wanted to read a string in Perl but i can't seems to get it right. The string is :

```
udp://10.111.80.95:8081
```

From this string, i want to only read the **ip address** part only which is :

```
10.111.80.95
```

And also i wanted to read the **port** part only which is :

```
8081
```

So with this i have 2 values that i can read which is the ip **address** and the **port**.

How can i achieve this? Do i need to use regex? But my regex had never get this right. Can anybody help me with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use regular expression for this needs, `split` is enough. You could split your string at `/` and `:`, then the third field is ip address and fourth field port number.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use feature qw(switch say);

use Data::Dumper;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @field = split /\/|:/;
    print "$field[3] $field[4]\n";
}

__DATA__
udp://10.111.80.95:8081
```

---

Running:

```
$ perl t.pl
10.111.80.95 8081
```